# SonarQube for multi module project for Android

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I have been through many articles and posts and sadly not a single one seems clear to me. I want to integrate sonarqube for my android project. The structure of my project is as below:

[image]

Initially, I had setup a single sonarqube.gradle the way it is mentioned here:[What is the correct way to configure an Android project with submodules for use with the sonarqube gradle plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438282/what-is-the-correct-way-to-configure-an-android-project-with-submodules-for-use)

But what it is doing for me is overwriting the data with the last module it processed. Which means I see code line in sonarqube login for only domain. If I do not add **apply from: '../sonarqube.gradle'**
in domain then I can see code for database. If I do not add **apply from: '../sonarqube.gradle'** in database and domain then I see it for data. So I am thinking its overwriting the logs.

Can someone help me to understand what is the right way to setup sonarqube for multimodule project in Android?

```
 apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

sonarqube {
  properties {
      property "sonar.projectName", "my-app"
      property "sonar.projectKey", "my-app"
      property "sonar.host.url", "URL"
      property "sonar.sources", "./src/main/"
      property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
      property "sonar.language", "kotlin"
      property "sonar.login", "token"
      property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.0"
      property "sonar.analysis.mode", "publish"
      property "sonar.android.lint.report", "./build/outputs/lint-results-debug.xml"
      property "sonar.exclusions", "**/BuildConfig.class,**/R.java,**/R\$*.java,src/main/gen/**/*,src/main/assets/**/*"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing Multi-Project Builds

Off doc link https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-gradle/

```
// build.gradle in:app
sonarqube {
    properties {
         property "sonar.*", "{value}"
    }
}

// build.gradle in :feature-module
subprojects {
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.*", "{value}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that you only need to apply the sonarqube plugin in the main project. Don't apply it in the build.gradel of subprojects.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the projectKey property and declare it only inside the root build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

sonarqube {
  properties {
      property "sonar.projectName", "my-app"
      property "sonar.host.url", "URL"
      property "sonar.sources", "./src/main/"
      property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
      property "sonar.language", "kotlin"
      property "sonar.login", "token"
      property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.0"
      property "sonar.analysis.mode", "publish"
      property "sonar.android.lint.report", "./build/outputs/lint-results-debug.xml"
      property "sonar.exclusions", "**/BuildConfig.class,**/R.java,**/R\$*.java,src/main/gen/**/*,src/main/assets/**/*"
  }
}
```